# Is a Bundle Display Name required

Tags: app-store, appstore-approval, tvos

I've made a tvOS application and submitted it to the App Store but I forgot to set the Bundle Display Name of my application in my `info.plist`. Now, when I install my application there is no name below my app icon.

Will Apple reject my application for not having a Bundle Display Name set?

Comment: *Is this can be the reason for the app rejection on app store?*, huh? Was your app approved or rejected?

Comment: Thats what i was asking. Can app gets rejected because of this reason. mY app is currently waiting for Review

Comment: Yes, check my answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns the policies and procedures of app distribution services, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?(https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bundle display name is required for your application to be approved for sale on the App Store.

You should reject the current binary, set the bundle display name of your application, and resubmit your application.

Comment: Is it mentioned some where in the apple Docs?

Comment: @Madu I'm unable to locate any docs stating this officially. I have had an application rejected for the display name on the Apple Watch version of the application not being set though.